# Implementing C# code that generates a string from an object field and field values

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, object

I have a code that is written in Javascript and I want to convert it to C#. What the code does is to get a javascript object and then creates a string using the key value pairs in object. How would you do something similar to this in C#.

Here is the javascript code

```
     const userSession = {
            application_id: 1111,
            auth_key: "abc123456,
            nonce: a456654,
            timestamp: 1254564,
            user: { 
                    login : "johnwick",
                    password: 123434543
            } 
        }



 signParams(userSession) {
        if (typeof userSession != 'object') {
            throw Error('not an object');
        }

        let signature = Object.keys(userSession)
            .map(elem => {
                if (typeof userSession[elem] === 'object') {
                    return Object.keys(userSession[elem])
                        .map(elem1 => {
                            return elem + '[' + elem1 + ']=' + userSession[elem][elem1];
                        })
                        .sort()
                        .join('&')
                }
                else {
                    return elem + '=' + userSession[elem]
                }
            })
            .sort()
            .join('&')



        return this.hmacSha1(signature);
    }

signParams(userSession)
```

The string should look like this
"application_id=3610&auth_key=aDRceQyTXSYEdJU&nonce=a456654&timestamp=${timestamp}&user[login]=johnwick&user[password]=123434543"

Here is how I initialize the object in c# using c# object since there is no object in c# that is similar to Javascript object

```
public class UserSession
    {
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string AuthKey { get; set; }
        public double Nonce { get; set; }
        public double Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Signature { get; set; }
        public dynamic User { get; set; }
    }


public async Task<Session> GenerateSessionParams(User user)
        {
            string filename = "config.json";
            using FileStream openStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
            Config config = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Config>(openStream);

          Session session = new Session();

            session.ApplicationId = config.cred.appId; 
            session.AuthKey = config.cred.authKey;
            session.Nonce = this.RandomNonce();
            session.Timestamp = this.GetTimeStamp();

            if (user.Login != default && user.Password != default)
            {
                session.User = new { Login = user.Login, Password = user.Password };
            }
            else if (user.Email != default && user.Password != default)
            {
                session.User = new { Email = user.Email, Password = user.Password };
            }



            return session;
        }
```

Comment: Why can't you use Newtonsoft in order to work with JSON?

Comment: I am new to the c# ecosystem so I didn't know much about it. I'm guessing you mean converting the javascript object to JSON using Newtonsoft in C# instead of creating a C# class?

Comment: See: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to convert your object into a query string.

I don't think c# has any in-built function to do so, you need to write your own function to do this.

Try using reflection to get Property names and their values at runtime and concat them into strings in a query string format.

Here is an article on how to do so.

[Serialize object into a query string with Reflection](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/serialize-object-into-a-query-string-with-reflection/)

I have taken the code snippet from article and changed few things according to your need.

```
 static string ConvertToQueryString(UserSession session)
        {
            var properties = session.GetType().GetProperties()
                        .Where(x => x.CanRead)
                        .Where(x => x.GetValue(session,null) != null)
                        .ToDictionary(x=>x.Name, x=>x.GetValue(session,null));
            
            var propertyNames = properties
            .Where(x => !(x.Value is string) && x.Value is IEnumerable)
            .Select(x => x.Key)
            .ToList();

             foreach (var key in propertyNames)
        {
            var valueType = properties[key].GetType();
            var valueElemType = valueType.IsGenericType
                                    ? valueType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
                                    : valueType.GetElementType();
            if (valueElemType.IsPrimitive || valueElemType == typeof (string))
            {
                var enumerable = properties[key] as IEnumerable;
                properties[key] = string.Join("&", enumerable.Cast<object>());
            }
        }
             return string.Join("&", properties
            .Select(x => string.Concat(
                Uri.EscapeDataString(x.Key), "=",
                Uri.EscapeDataString(x.Value.ToString()))));
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Like in the article, it is better to create an extension method if you want to chain this function.

Read More about Extension Functions: [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)